# Python change multiple dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am using jupyter notebook and getting data using API.

I have a list of names.

```
names = ['a','b','c','d']
for name in names:
    df=library.function(name)
    print(df)
```

Then I get multiple dictionaries.

```
{'name':'a', 'level':2, 'quality': 12}
{'name':'b', 'level':3, 'quality': 14}
{'name':'c', 'level':6, 'quality': 13}
{'name':'d', 'level':2, 'quality': 11}
```

The dictionaries are not defined as something like dict_1 ~ dict_4 or these are not a list of multiple dictionaries, so I have no idea what to do :(
Is there any way that I can change/merge these multiple dictionaries to a pandas dataframe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put dictionaries into a list in the loop and then cast to a DataFrame:

```
dicts_list = []  # to hold the dictionaries
names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for name in names:
    new_dict = library.function(name)
    dicts_list.append(new_dict)  # store it

# make a frame
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(dicts_list)
```

to get

```
>>> data_frame
  name  level  quality
0    a      2       12
1    b      3       14
2    c      6       13
3    d      2       11
```

But this "make a list - turn a loop - append to it" calls for [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), so:

```
dicts_list = [library.function(name) for name in names]
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(dicts_list)
```

You can also skip the intermediary variable `dicts_list`:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame([library.function(name) for name in names])
```

Lastly, you can even drop the `[]` to make it a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)!

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(library.function(name) for name in names)
```

All give the same result.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can add a list and it will create for you automatic data frame

```
import pandas as pd 
list_t =[
        {'name':'a', 'level':2, 'quality': 12},
        {'name':'b', 'level':3, 'quality': 14},
        {'name':'c', 'level':6, 'quality': 13},
        {'name':'d', 'level':2, 'quality': 11}
         ]



pd.DataFrame(list_t)


#output

    name    level   quality
0   a        2        12
1   b        3        14
2   c        6        13
3   d        2        11
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this wasn't the answer... It solved my problem in 2 seconds! Thanks! Sometimes I overthink stuff and try to make life a lot harder than it needs to be. Then this comes along and reminds me to stop being complicated... lol